# How to refresh jtable after insert data in jdialog?

Tags: java, swing, hibernate, model-view-controller, jdbc

I have internal jframe **Employee List** and jdialog **AddEditEmployee** when I click on Save button I wish refresh jtable in **Employee List** and then **AddEditEmployee** was cleared.

I am trying invoke **isTableModel** method in Save button actionListener but it isn't working.

Please see [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uoh3g.png) and code below:

**Employee Controller**

```
public class EmployeeController {
private EmployeeList employeeList_view;
private AddEditEmployee addEditEmployee_view;
private ImplementEmployeeList implementEmployeeList;
private List<Employees> employees;

public EmployeeController(EmployeeList employeeList_view) {
    this.employeeList_view = employeeList_view;
    implementEmployeeList = new EmployeeDAO();
    employees = implementEmployeeList.getEmployeeList();
}

public EmployeeController(AddEditEmployee addEditEmployee_view){
    this.addEditEmployee_view = addEditEmployee_view;
    implementEmployeeList = new EmployeeDAO();
    employees = implementEmployeeList.getEmployeeList();
}

public void reset(){
    addEditEmployee_view.getJtfEmployeeID().setText("");
    addEditEmployee_view.getJtfFirstName().setText("");
    addEditEmployee_view.getJtfLastName().setText("");
}

public void isTableModel(){
    employees = implementEmployeeList.getEmployeeList();
    EmployeeTableModel employeeTableModel = new EmployeeTableModel(employees);
    employeeList_view.getJtbEmployeeList().setModel(employeeTableModel);
}

public void insert(){
    Employees emp = new Employees();
    Functions func = new Functions();

    emp.setEmployee_code(Integer.parseInt(addEditEmployee_view.getJtfEmployeeID().getText()));
    emp.setFirst_name(addEditEmployee_view.getJtfFirstName().getText());
    emp.setLast_name(addEditEmployee_view.getJtfLastName().getText());
    emp.setGender(addEditEmployee_view.getJcbGender().getSelectedItem().toString());
    emp.setDate_of_birth(addEditEmployee_view.getDateOfBirth().getDate());
    emp.setHire_date(addEditEmployee_view.getHireDate().getDate());
    emp.setMarital_status(addEditEmployee_view.getJcbMaritalStatus().getSelectedItem().toString());
    emp.setPhoto(func.convertBufferedImageToBlob(addEditEmployee_view.getJlbPhoto()));
    implementEmployeeList.insert(emp);
}

public void update(){
    Employees emp = new Employees();
    //emp.setEmployee_code(Integer.parseInt(addEditEmployee_view.getJtfEmployeeID().getText()));
    emp.setFirst_name(addEditEmployee_view.getJtfFirstName().getText());
    emp.setLast_name(addEditEmployee_view.getJtfLastName().getText());
    emp.setGender(addEditEmployee_view.getJcbGender().getSelectedItem().toString());
    emp.setDate_of_birth(addEditEmployee_view.getDateOfBirth().getDate());
    emp.setHire_date(addEditEmployee_view.getHireDate().getDate());
    emp.setMarital_status(addEditEmployee_view.getJcbMaritalStatus().getSelectedItem().toString());
    implementEmployeeList.update(emp);
}

public void delete(){
    implementEmployeeList.delete((Integer) employeeList_view.getJtbEmployeeList().getValueAt(employeeList_view.getJtbEmployeeList().getSelectedRow(),1));
}
```

}
**Employee TableModel**

```
public class EmployeeTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

List<Employees> employeesList;

public EmployeeTableModel(List<Employees> employeesList) {
    this.employeesList = employeesList;
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return employeesList.size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return 12;
}

@Override
public String getColumnName(int column) {
    switch (column){
        case 0: return "No";
        case 1: return "Employee ID";
        case 2: return "First Name";
        case 3: return "Last Name";
        case 4: return "Gender";
        case 5: return "Date of Birth";
        case 6: return "Marital Status";
        case 7: return "Hire Date";
        case 8: return "Address";
        case 9: return "Telephone";
        case 10: return "Email";
        case 11: return "Notes";
        default: return null;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
    switch (columnIndex){
        case 0: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getEmployee_id();
        case 1: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getEmployee_code();
        case 2: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getFirst_name();
        case 3: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getLast_name();
        case 4: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getGender();
        case 5: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getDate_of_birth();
        case 6: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getMarital_status();
        case 7: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getHire_date();
        case 8: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getAddress();
        case 9: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getTelephone();
        case 10: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getEmail();
        case 11: return employeesList.get(rowIndex).getNotes();
        default: return null;
    }
}
```

}

**AddEditEmployee_View**

```
public class AddEditEmployee extends JDialog implements ActionListener {
private JPanel jpParents;
private JPanel jpProfilePicture;
private JLabel jlbPhoto;
private JButton jbBrowse;
private JTextField jtfEmployeeID;
private JTextField jtfFirstName;
private JTextField jtfLastName;
private JComboBox jcbGender;
private JComboBox jcbMaritalStatus;
private JTextField jtfAddress;
private JComboBox jcbProvince;
private JTextField jtfPostalCode;
private JTextField jtfPhone;
private JComboBox jcbDistrict;
private JTextField jtfEmail;
private JTextArea jtaNotes;
private JButton jbSave;
private JPanel jpBirthDay;
private JPanel jpHireDate;
private JDateChooser dateOfBirth;
private JDateChooser hireDate;

private enum gender {Male, Female}
private enum marital {Single, Married, devise}

private Functions func;
private EmployeeController employeeController;
private Image image = null;

public JButton getJbBrowse() {
    return jbBrowse;
}

public JTextField getJtfEmployeeID() {
    return jtfEmployeeID;
}

public JTextField getJtfFirstName() {
    return jtfFirstName;
}

public JTextField getJtfLastName() {
    return jtfLastName;
}

public JComboBox getJcbGender() {
    return jcbGender;
}

public JDateChooser getDateOfBirth() {
    return dateOfBirth;
}

public JDateChooser getHireDate() {
    return hireDate;
}

public JComboBox getJcbMaritalStatus() {
    return jcbMaritalStatus;
}

public JTextField getJtfAddress() {
    return jtfAddress;
}

public JComboBox getJcbProvince() {
    return jcbProvince;
}

public JTextField getJtfPostalCode() {
    return jtfPostalCode;
}

public JTextField getJtfPhone() {
    return jtfPhone;
}

public JComboBox getJcbDistrict() {
    return jcbDistrict;
}

public JTextField getJtfEmail() {
    return jtfEmail;
}

public JTextArea getJtaNotes() {
    return jtaNotes;
}

public JButton getJbSave() {
    return jbSave;
}

public JLabel getJlbPhoto() {
    return jlbPhoto;
}

public AddEditEmployee() {
    super();
    setContentPane(jpParents);
    setTitle("Add New Employee");
    image = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/newEmployee-16.png")).getImage();
    setIconImage(image);
    setSize(new Dimension(850, 580));
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setOperationAction();

    func = new Functions();

    try {
        func = new Functions();
        Color color = this.getBackground();
        jpProfilePicture.add(func.setCircleImage(jlbPhoto, 200, 200, "src/images/avatar.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    dateOfBirth = new JDateChooser();
    dateOfBirth.setOpaque(false);
    dateOfBirth.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(165, 25));
    dateOfBirth.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    dateOfBirth.getCalendarButton().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(24,24));
    dateOfBirth.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/calendar.png")));
    jpBirthDay.add(dateOfBirth);

    hireDate = new JDateChooser();
    hireDate.setOpaque(false);
    hireDate.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(165, 25));
    hireDate.setDateFormatString("dd/MM/yyyy");
    hireDate.getCalendarButton().setPreferredSize(new Dimension(24,24));
    hireDate.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/calendar.png")));
    jpHireDate.add(hireDate);

    jcbGender.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(gender.values()));
    jcbMaritalStatus.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(marital.values()));

}

private void setOperationAction(){
    jbBrowse.addActionListener(this);
    jbSave.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == jbBrowse){
        func = new Functions();
        func.browserImage(jlbPhoto, 200, 200);
    } else if (e.getSource() == jbSave){
        employeeController = new EmployeeController(this);
        employeeController.insert();
        employeeController.isTableModel();
    }
}
```

}
**EmployeeList_View**

```
public class EmployeeList extends JInternalFrame implements ActionListener {
private JPanel jpParents;
private JTable jtbEmployeeList;
private JPanel jpSearchBar;
private JPanel jpOperator;
private JPanel jpOperation;
private JPanel jpPaginator;
private JButton jbAdd;
private JButton jbEdit;
private JButton jbDelete;
private EmployeeController empcontroller;

public JTable getJtbEmployeeList() {

    return jtbEmployeeList;
}

public JButton getJbAdd() {

    return jbAdd;
}

public JButton getJbEdit() {
    return jbEdit;
}

public JButton getJbDelete() {
    return jbDelete;
}

private JScrollPane jspEmployeeList;

private final String colHeader[] = {"No", "Employee ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "Gender", "Date of Birth",
"Marital Status", "Hire Date", "Address", "Telephone", "Email", "Note"};
private DefaultTableModel model;

public EmployeeList(String title, boolean resizable, boolean closable, boolean maximizable, boolean iconifiable) {
    super(title, resizable, closable, maximizable, iconifiable);
    setContentPane(jpParents);
    setSize(850, 500);
    setFrameIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/employee_list.png")));

    JSearchTextField jtfSearch = new JSearchTextField();
    jtfSearch.setColumns(15);
    jtfSearch.setIcon(new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("/images/search18.png")));
    jtfSearch.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(30,27));
    jpSearchBar.add(jtfSearch);

    setOperatorAction();

    empcontroller = new EmployeeController(this);
    empcontroller.isTableModel();
}

private void setOperatorAction(){
    jbAdd.addActionListener(this);
    jbEdit.addActionListener(this);
    jbDelete.addActionListener(this);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == jbAdd){
        new AddEditEmployee().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

}
**EmployeeDAO**

```
public class EmployeeDAO implements ImplementEmployeeList{
Connection connection;

final String insert = "INSERT INTO employees(employees_code, first_name, last_name, gender, date_of_birth, hire_date, marital_status, photo) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
final String update = "UPDATE employees SET first_name = ?, last_name = ?, gender = ?, date_of_birth = ?, hire_date = ?, marital_status = ?, photo = ? WHERE employees_code = ?";
final String delete = "DELETE FROM employees WHERE employees_code = ?";
final String select = "SELECT * FROM employees";
final String search = "SELECT * FROM employees WHERE employees_code = ?";

public EmployeeDAO() {
    this.connection = ConnectionConfiguraion.getConnection();
}

@Override
public void insert(Employees emp) {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    Functions func = new Functions();

    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(insert, PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        statement.setInt(1, emp.getEmployee_code());
        statement.setString(2, emp.getFirst_name());
        statement.setString(3, emp.getLast_name());
        statement.setString(4, emp.getGender());
        statement.setDate(5, new Date(emp.getDate_of_birth().getTime()));
        statement.setDate(6, new Date(emp.getHire_date().getTime()));
        statement.setString(7, emp.getMarital_status());
        statement.setBinaryStream(8, emp.getPhoto().getBinaryStream());
        statement.executeUpdate();

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "New record was inserted successfully.", "Message", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);

        ResultSet rs = statement.getGeneratedKeys();
        while (rs.next()){
            emp.setEmployee_id(rs.getInt(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void update(Employees emp) {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(update);
        //statement.setInt(1, emp.getEmployee_code());
        statement.setString(1, emp.getFirst_name());
        statement.setString(2, emp.getLast_name());
        statement.setString(3, emp.getGender());
        statement.setDate(4, (Date) emp.getDate_of_birth());
        statement.setDate(5, (Date) emp.getHire_date());
        statement.setString(6, emp.getMarital_status());
        statement.setInt(7, emp.getEmployee_code());
        statement.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public void delete(int id) {
    PreparedStatement statement = null;

    try {
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(delete);
        statement.setInt(1, id);
        statement.executeUpdate();

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            statement.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@Override
public List<Employees> getEmployeeList() {
    List<Employees> employeesList = null;

    try {
        employeesList = new ArrayList<Employees>();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(select);

        while (resultSet.next()){
            Employees employees = new Employees();
            employees.setEmployee_id(resultSet.getInt("employeesid"));
            employees.setEmployee_code(resultSet.getInt("employees_code"));
            employees.setFirst_name(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
            employees.setLast_name(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
            employees.setGender(resultSet.getString("gender"));
            employees.setDate_of_birth(resultSet.getDate("date_of_birth"));
            employees.setHire_date(resultSet.getDate("hire_date"));
            employees.setMarital_status(resultSet.getString("marital_status"));
            employees.setPhoto(resultSet.getBlob("photo"));
            employeesList.add(employees);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return employeesList;
}

@Override
public List<Employees> getSearch(int employee_code) {
    List<Employees> employeesList = null;

    try {
        employeesList = new ArrayList<Employees>();
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(search);

        while (resultSet.next()){
            Employees employees = new Employees();
            employees.setEmployee_id(resultSet.getInt("employeesid"));
            employees.setEmployee_code(resultSet.getInt("employees_code"));
            employees.setFirst_name(resultSet.getString("first_name"));
            employees.setLast_name(resultSet.getString("last_name"));
            employees.setGender(resultSet.getString("gender"));
            employees.setDate_of_birth(resultSet.getTimestamp("date_of_birth"));
            employees.setHire_date(resultSet.getTimestamp("hire_date"));
            employees.setMarital_status(resultSet.getString("marital_status"));
            employeesList.add(employees);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return employeesList;

}
```

}

Comment: you can either add/remove the data and row from/to the table model. or what is much easier, you select all data from database, store it in a list and set the list as table model data. for the second way you have to remove all rows from the tablemodel first

Comment: Yes! indeed, I try to insert new data into database and then I had invoked **isTableModel()** method to fill data into jtable. Please see isTableModel() method invoked by Save button in **AddEditEmployee** class. Note: **isTableModel** method is use to fill and get all records from database to stored in list.